# Concatenate strings in foreach loop with array key

Tags: php, arrays, string, oop

I've got a function, which takes in a string parameter for the name of specific page section, this can either be `head` or `body`.

The function looks like this:

```
private $html = [];

public function doStuff($pageSection, array $views)
{
    foreach ($views as $view) {
        //Do some other stuff with view

        $this->html[$pageSection] .= $view->renderOutput();
    }

    print_r($this->html);
}
```

The `renderOutput()` function from `$view` returns a string, and isn't throwing any errors.

When trying to add this string to the `$this->html` array in a specific array key (the `$pageSection`), I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: body in
>   C:\file.php on line 35

While in the next line (`print_r($this->html);`, the array is filled with all the strings I wanted to add in the right array key, `body`.

The function get's called like this:

```
doStuff('body', array(
           //Array of views
         ));
```

I tried to remove the concatenate operator and just change the string inside the array key, this threw the same error.

How is this happening? Since I already added the array key in the `$this->html[$pageSection]` part.

Also, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I Don't see anything with `body` here. Maybe it's in `renderOutput`?

Comment: try `print_r` out `pageSection` what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String

```
$this->html[$pageSection] .= 'some data';
```

means that you concatenate `'some data'` to value that **should** already exist.

In case you don't have key `'body'` in `$this->html` and trying to concatenate to it - you'll see this **notice**.

You can try something like:

```
foreach ($views as $view) {
    //Do some other stuff with view

    // init value with empty string.
    if (!isset($this->html[$pageSection])) {
        $this->html[$pageSection] = '';  
    }

    $this->html[$pageSection] .= $view->renderOutput();
}
```

Comment: may I suggest to move that check outside the foreach loop. No need to check it on each iteration, since the `$pageSection` is constant.

Comment: This did the job! thank you. But why is it possible when you're not in a loop and do something like `$array['randKey'] = 123;` it works without the error?

Comment: Because `$array['randKey'] = 123;` means `create key randKey and assign 123 to it`. See - there's no concatenation. Check `$array['randKey'] .= 123;` and you will get a warning.

Comment: It gave the same error when I tried to just assign the string to the array key?

Comment: No, it won't. See the difference between assigning `=` and concatenating `.=`.